# Axios post request not getting resolved

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, request

I've spent hours trying to figure out why this axios post request is not being completed. If i make this request using postman, it just keeps rolling and doesnt return a response which its supposed to.

```
router.post("/api/epic", async (req , res) => {
  let auth =
    "Basic " + Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString("base64")
  const { code } = req.body
  const url = "https://api.epicgames.dev/epic/oauth/v1/token"
  const values = new URLSearchParams({
    code,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    scope: "basic_profile",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
  })

  // console.log(auth)

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, values, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Authorization": auth,
      },
    })
    console.log(res)
    return res.data
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    // throw new Error(error.message)
  }
})
```

it keeps returning a `Request failed with status code 400` error from the `catch` block but i can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. could you please be more specific

Comment: You have two `res` identifiers in your code: 1. parameter `res` and the constant `res` that is assigned the result of `await axios.post(...)`. Also, returning `res.data` doesn't sends a response to the client; use `res.send(...)`

Comment: Switched it to this and still the same. the try block is being completely ignored. thanks for ur time Yousaf

Comment: Try adding `res.send(error)` in the `catch` block.

Comment: it returns `Request failed with status code 400`. which means bad request but just cant figure out whats bad in my code

Comment: That is most likely because of `await axios.post(url, values, { ... }` - Where are you sending this request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237052/discussion-between-muhammed-a-o-and-yousaf).

Comment: I'm sending it from my index file

Comment: I mean where are you sending this request to? Also, remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - it is set by the server, not the client.

Comment: Sending it here https://api.epicgames.dev/epic/oauth/v1/token